# The "local" directive in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I was sitting around debugging some code and I stumbled across this line in SysUtils.pas:

```
procedure ConvertError(ResString: PResStringRec); local;
```

What does the local keyword do exactly? It seems the ConvertError function is not declared in the interface section of the file, is this just a clarification that the function is indeed local, or is there a practical benefit to using this directive beyond that?

Comment: It seems that, the directive ensures there's no declaration in the interface (causes a compile time error otherwise). Interesting...

Comment: Did you try to read the documentation for this keyword?

Comment: @wRAR I hit f1 on it but the built in documentation couldn't find it. Then I checked Google and came up with nothing and here we are ;)

Comment: @wRAR "local" is not a very specific search term. And since the current documentation doesn't have it you need to either: 1. Already know the answer, or 2. Have a physical copy of some old documentation with a good index. Option 2 was my route.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yay for undocumented keywords.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It dates back to the Linux compiler, Kylix. Here's what I can see in my Delphi 6 language guide, page 9-4:

> The directive **local**, which marks routines as unavailable for export, is platform-specific and has no effect in Windows programming.
>
> On Linux, the **local** directive provides a slight performance optimization for routines that are compiled into a library, but are not exported. The directive can be specified for standalone procedures and functions, but not for methods. A routine declared with **local**—for example.
>
> ```
> function Contraband(I: Integer): Integer; local;
> ```
>
> —does not refresh the EBX register and hence
>
> - cannot be exported from a library.
> - cannot be declared in the **interface** section of a unit.
> - cannot have its address take or be assigned to a procedural-type variable.
> - if it is a pure assembler routine, cannot be called from a another unit unless the *caller* sets up EBX.

Comment: Here is a [link](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate4/EN/html/devcommon/dynamicallyloadedlibs_xml.html) to the embarcadero documentation about the local directive.

Comment: @RRUZ I also found that by typing in the text in my answer! Delphi 2007 though. Old school.

Comment: Ah, good old "local" and the EBX GOT pointer calling convention. Some things about Linux I do not miss...